# error : The imported project was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

BUILD ERROR: When I load the solution file in Visual Studio, it says file failed to load. The full error says:

```
C:\path\to\project.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\path\to\target.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration  is correct, and that the file exists on disk
```

I checked and the targets file exists in that path

I am using Visual Studio 2019. If I try to build from the command line, it fails as well. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Right now I cannot run let alone build my project

Comment: Did the error occurs when you install a nuget? If so, what is the nuget? Did you check the error path and make sure that the path is right without any error? Usually, we use `<Import Project="C:\path\to\target.targets">` in the xxx.csproj file. [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders), delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then build again.

Comment: That "\" isn't the error because that path is just what the error messaged said, I missed a "\" when typing it here on StackOverflow but it's written properly in the error message. I cannot build because if I try to build from the command line, I get this error: MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch. Switch: /m:4

Comment: Was it a targets file import into the csproj by the import node?

Comment: Yes, in the csproj file, the problematic file is in the import project node, it looks like:

<Import Project="$(BaseDir)\path\to\target.targets" />

If I follow this path, I verify that this file exists.

Comment: Quite strange. If I call Developer Command prompt for VS2019 and type `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj /m:4`, I did not face the issue and works well in my side. 1) Please try to disable any third party extensions under Extensions-->Manage Extensions in case they caused the issue. 2) reset all vs settings under `Tools`-->`Import and Export Settings` 3) delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder 4) [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update VS to the latest version

Comment: I have added an answer and you can check it. Any feedback will be expected.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: This error may also occur when you clone a repository with a space in the name. The default name for the folder can have `%20` in the name. This is a problem. If you have this: commit and push all changes, delete the repo folder from your machine, and re-clone the repo this time to a folder with no spaces or `%20` in the name.

Comment: What if the path doesn't exist? How Visual Studio came up with the specific path if it doesn't exist? How can I proceed from now on and fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

**Actually**, it is quite strange and should not be an issue since you just quote the `import` method and make sure the path of the file  is correct.

Not sure whether your project or vs has broken.

Please try to the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

**First of All**, make sure that the targets file on the folder path `C:\path\to` is the same as `target.targets` and make sure it exists.

**1)** close VS delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**2)** open VS IDE, click Menu **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** and then disable any installed extensions to check whether it is caused by them.

**3)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset All Settings** and you can make a backup before you do it.

**4)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update vs to the latest version.

Also, you can use type [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) under **Developer Command Prompt for VS2019** to start VS and then test your project.

**Besides**, you can create a new project and do the same step to import that targets file to check whether the issue occurs in the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project name or root folder name of your project not contain /